# JFrame showing empty when start socket server

Tags: java, swing, serversocket, event-dispatch-thread

When the code uses a socket, the receiving frame loads empty.
It does not add `fileNameLabel`, `headerLabel` or `scrollFile` and if I remove the socket then it loads all added Swing components.

How can I deal with it?

This is the full code of receive files:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
// import java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor.Builder;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

// import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

// import javax.swing.border.Border;
// import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
// import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;

class App {

    public static File[] file = new File[1];

    public static void receiveFile() {

        JFrame receiveFileFrame;
        JPanel receiveFilePanel;
        JLabel fileNameLabel, headerLabel;

        receiveFileFrame = new JFrame();
        receiveFilePanel = new JPanel();
        fileNameLabel = new JLabel();
        headerLabel = new JLabel();

        receiveFileFrame.setBounds(750, 300, 400, 400);
        receiveFileFrame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(receiveFileFrame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JScrollPane scrollFiles = new JScrollPane(receiveFilePanel);
        scrollFiles.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        fileNameLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        fileNameLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        headerLabel.setText("Received Files");
        headerLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        headerLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        receiveFilePanel.add(fileNameLabel);

        receiveFileFrame.add(headerLabel);
        receiveFileFrame.add(scrollFiles);

        receiveFileFrame.setVisible(true);

        receiveFileFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        try {

            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                int fileNameLength = dataInputStream.readInt();
                byte[] fileNameSize = new byte[fileNameLength];
                dataInputStream.readFully(fileNameSize, 0, fileNameSize.length);
                String fileName = new String(fileNameSize);
                fileNameLabel.setText(fileName);
                int fileContentLength = dataInputStream.readInt();
                byte[] fileContentSize = new byte[fileContentLength];
                dataInputStream.readFully(fileContentSize, 0, fileContentLength);
                File fileDownload = new File(fileName);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileDownload);
                fileOutputStream.write(fileContentSize);
                fileOutputStream.close();
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(receiveFileFrame, e, "Message", 0);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
        JButton send, receive;
        JPanel mainPanel, buttoPanel;
        JLabel heading;
        // Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);

        heading = new JLabel();
        send = new JButton();
        receive = new JButton();
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        buttoPanel = new JPanel();

        mainFrame.setBounds(700, 250, 400, 200);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainFrame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        heading.setText("File Transfer");
        heading.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        heading.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        send.setText("Send");
        send.setSize(100, 50);
        send.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));

        receive.setText("Receive");
        receive.setSize(100, 50);
        receive.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));

        buttoPanel.add(send);
        buttoPanel.add(receive);

        mainPanel.add(heading);
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        mainPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
        mainPanel.add(buttoPanel);

        mainFrame.add(mainPanel);

        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainFrame, "Send feature not added", "Message", 0);

            }
        });

        receive.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                receiveFile();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Don't block the Event Dispatch Thread. See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for details. 2) *"it will be easy solve error"* How could you know it will be easy when you do not know what the solution is? Don't presume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling method `receiveFile` on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (EDT). Method `receiveFile` contains the following line:

```java
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
```

Here is a quote from the [*javadoc*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()) of method `accept`:

> The method blocks until a connection is made.

In other words, when you run your program, its execution will stop at the above line until a socket connection is made. Thus you have literally stopped the EDT. If the EDT is stopped then it can't paint anything and that's why

> It does not add `fileNameLabel`, `headerLabel` or `scrollFile`

And that's also why

> if I remove the socket then it loads all added Swing components

You need to run your socket code on a separate thread.
You can either use a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) or create a new `Thread` to run your socket code and update the GUI from that thread by calling method [invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) of class `java.awt.EventQueue`. Note that you will probably find a lot of examples that use method `invokeLater` of class `javax.swing.SwingUtilities`. That method simply calls the same name method in class `java.awt.EventQueue`.